# Show image on php int change

Tags: php, json

In PHP how do I make it show an image when an int changes from 0 to 1? I have;

```
$url = "forums.bukkit.org/alerts.json";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$json_arr = json_decode($string,true);
return $json_arr['_visitor_alertsUnread'];
```

When json_arr is >0, how do I make it show an image?

Comment: Where do you want to show an image?

Comment: It's actually for a chrome extension, but just so I can figure it out, just on a web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($json_arr['_visitor_alertsUnread'])
   echo "seen picture!";
else
   echo "not seen picture!";
```

Comment: why you can change if to if($json_arr['_visitor_alertsUnread']>0)

Comment: you can echo your image instead of a string
echo "<img src=\"seen.png\" />";